# Problem installing qt5-default on Ubuntu 22.04 - needed to install IQmol

Tags: qt5, ubuntu-22.04

While installing IQmol is relatively easy in ubuntu 20.04, with Ubuntu 22.04 there is a problem with the qt5-default package that seems to have been updated for this new LTS version of Ubuntu.

In the manual it says the following, after downloading iqmol_2.14.deb from their website:
"*`#> sudo dpkg -i iqmol_x.x.x.x.deb` #> sudo apt-get install -f```
The second command is required to resolve the dependency on the Qt libraries, which
you may not have installed.*"

From the first command the error is as follows:
"*dpkg: dependency issues prevent iqmol configuration:
iqmol depends on qt5-default; however:
**The qt5-default package is not installed.**
dpkg: error processing iqmol package (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Errors encountered while processing
iqmol*"

And from the second:
"***The following packages will be REMOVED:
iqmol**
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/N]*"

I have searched, unsuccessfully, for a way to install qt5-default manually on Ubuntu 22.04, but I still don't see how.

Please, someone who can point out the step-by-step.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting, unsuccessfully, for a while for the Ubuntu 22.04 repositories to allow installing the old version of qt5-default, I got the idea to install IQmol for Windows (iqmol.exe) via **Wine**.

Indeed that was the best option and solution to my problem. I totally recommend it.